# Email contact-form based in php and html not working

Tags: php, email, contact-form

I'm creating a website with a template from templateforest. I have an HTML contact form which is integrated at the bottom of the site and it is related with a PHP file for the submit process.

Here you are the code from the HTML part:

```
<!--contact section start-->
<div class="section section-contact" id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <!--tittle start-->
                <div class="tittle">
                    <h1>
                        <a name="contactar"><span>10</span></a>
                        Contactar</h1>
                    <h2>
                        <span> Si deseas ponerte en contacto conmigo por favor, rellena el siguiente formulario o si lo prefieres utiliza los datos de contacto facilitados al pie de esta página.</span>
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <!--tittle end-->
                <div class="contact-row">
                    <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <textarea name="comments" placeholder="Comments" class="form-control" rows="10" cols="30" id="msg" name=""></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row form-group text-center">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <button type="submit" id="submit" class="view-btn">Contactar con Patricia</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--contact section end-->
```

And this is the code from sendmail.php file:

```
<?php
// Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0
if ( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['comments']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

  // detect & prevent header injections
  $mailTest = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
  foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
    if ( preg_match( $mailTest, $val ) ) {
      exit;
    }
  }

$headers = 'From: ' . $_POST["name"] . '<' . $_POST["email"] . '>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

  mail( "info@example.com", $_POST['subject'], $_POST['comments'], $headers );
  //  Replace with your email 
}
?>
```

Obviously I've replaced the "info@example.com" with a valid email... but it didn't work.

I've looking for similar codes but I'm not very good at php so I can't find the solution.

When I push on "submit" button at the site, it just reloads the whole page... and that's all... no error message but also no email sent.

The php version of the server is 5.4.

EDIT AT 13/05/2015:

This is the PHP File code after the changes I've performed as they were sugested:

```
<?php
//this is to activate error messages
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0
if ( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['comments']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

  // detect & prevent header injections
  $mailTest = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
  foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
    if ( preg_match( $mailTest, $val ) ) {
      exit;
    }
  }

$headers = 'From: ' . $_POST["name"] . '<' . $_POST["email"] . '>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if(mail( "info@example.com", $subject, $comment, $headers )){
   echo "Mail sent, it's out of your hands now and it did its job.";
}

else{
   echo "There was an error, check your logs.";
}
  //  Replace with your email 
}
?>
```

EDIT 2:

Now the HTML code looks like this:

```
<!--contact section start-->
<div class="section section-contact" id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <!--tittle start-->
                <div class="tittle">
                    <h1>
                        <a name="contactar"><span>10</span></a>
                        Contactar</h1>
                    <h2>
                        <span> Si deseas ponerte en contacto conmigo por favor, rellena el siguiente formulario o si lo prefieres utiliza los datos de contacto facilitados al pie de esta página.</span>
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <!--tittle end-->
                <div class="contact-row">
                    <form role="form" class="form-horizontal" action="sendmail.php">
                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <textarea name="comments" placeholder="Comments" class="form-control" rows="10" cols="30" id="msg" name=""></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row form-group text-center">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <button type="submit" id="submit" class="view-btn">Contactar con Patricia</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Forms default to GET if a POST method isn't explicitly used. You're using POST arrays, so make your form a POST method. Unless you've got some JS/Ajax you're not showing us that does have a [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or POST method in there. Therefore, there's no way for me to submit this as an "answer", *per se*. Not without knowing if that's your complete code or not.

Comment: *"I've bought a template at templateforest but when asking to the author he never gave me any answer."* - Sucks doesn't it? I've responded, so don't do like them too ;-)

Comment: I have several .js files in a paralel directory.... /js however there isn't anyone which seems related with the mail service... Is there any common code that I can look for in all of them to find if there is one? I will post then the complete code of the JS file here to help.

Comment: is this bootstrap by any chance?

Comment: Yes it is... I think it is twitter bootstrap

Comment: I thought so. The problem could be inside one of the `.js` files. I had that same problem before, but now to remember exactly what it was, might take some time to find it again.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, at least they helps me to look for a solution in the .js files instead of looking for it on the php files... :)

Comment: If you have this same filename `contact_me.js` have a look in there and make sure there is a POST method marked. Or now that I've found my files, use `<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" action="sendmail.php">` there is no action in your form tag. Try that.

Comment: Hi, I'm back! There is no contact_me.js file... so I'm going to try with the other suggestion that you mentioned before. Let's se...

Comment: Well after replacing the original HTML line with this '<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" action="sendmail.php">' I've made another test and now the page gets blank after pressing submit button. I've noticied that also at the browser's url I can see something like: 'htp://thedomain/sendmail.php?name=Dani&email=example@domaincom&subject=bla+bla&comments=bla+bla+bla'

Comment: Try doing `<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" action="sendmail.php" method="post">` see if that makes it kick in.

Comment: Great! now there is some more progress... after adding the line that you mentioned now I've recieved an email, however it was a blank email... but at least is more than nothing :) by the other side I've also get an error message on the page:
 
Notice: Undefined variable: subject in /var/www/vhosts/thedomain/httpdocs/sendmail.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined variable: comment in /var/www/vhosts/thedomain/httpdocs/sendmail.php on line 21
 Mail sent, it's out of your hands now and it did its job

Comment: Sorry for disturbing again but I'm not sure where should I add that line on the PHP file. thanks

Comment: reload my answer below and look at the bottom under **Edit**, there's a rewrite

Comment: It Works!!! thanks a lot!!! :D I'm going to mark it as solved! thanks again!

Comment: Great and you're welcome. Glad to see it was resolved, *cheers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that what you posted for code, am submitting the following and taken from my comments.

- Forms default to a GET method if a POST method isn't explicitly used.

You're using POST arrays, so make your form a POST method.

```
<form method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Unless you've got some JS/Ajax you're not showing us that does have a [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or POST method in there, you will need to post that, *after the fact*.

> *"no error message but also no email sent."*

That's because you're not checking for them.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

**Footnotes:**

You shouldn't pass POST arrays like this:

```
mail( "info@example.com", $_POST['subject'], $_POST['comments'], $headers );
```

You're leaving yourself open to XSS injection.

You should use pre-assigned variables.

```
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$comment = $_POST['comments'];
...

mail( "info@example.com", $subject, $comment, $headers );
```

or

```
if(mail( "info@example.com", $subject, $comment, $headers )){
   echo "Mail sent, it's out of your hands now and it did its job.";
}

else{
   echo "There was an error, check your logs.";
}
```

---

XSS injection articles:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting
- [Cross-site Scripting (XSS) - OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29)

---

**Edit:**

```
<?php
//this is to activate error messages
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0
if ( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['comments']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

  // detect & prevent header injections
  $mailTest = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
  foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
    if ( preg_match( $mailTest, $val ) ) {
      exit;
    }
  }

$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$comment = $_POST['comments'];

$headers = 'From: ' . $_POST["name"] . '<' . $_POST["email"] . '>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if(mail( "info@example.com", $subject, $comment, $headers )){
   echo "Mail sent, it's out of your hands now and it did its job.";
}

else{
   echo "There was an error, check your logs.";
}
  //  Replace with your email 
}
?>
```

Comment: Let's see if the OP responds to this.

Comment: thanks for your answers! I I'm anoob at this kind of scritps so I'm not sure about what you are meaning when you talk about POST. Anyway I'm adding and replacing the code as you mention and I will post the results in a few minutes....

EDIT: still no luck... not error shown and not email recieved :(

Comment: @DanielMartinez You're welcome. Now, this `<form role="form" class="form-horizontal">` is missing `method="post"` by not using that, it's as if you were using `<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="get">` which makes your form fail.

Comment: Does that mean that changing the GET method by the missing POST method would solve the problem? or would I be still failing due to the .js corrupt file?

Comment: @DanielMartinez Try doing that first, adding `method="post"` to the form tag as outlined. It definitely needs a POST method.

Comment: OK, I gotta go right now... I will try it in a while and I will post the result. Thanks again!

Comment: @DanielMartinez You're welcome Daniel. See my other comment that I left you under your question. I'm pretty sure that ought to solve it, this about the `action` in the form tag.